# What is the false parameter in .delete(False)?

Tags: django

I used an example from [here](https://cmljnelson.blog/2020/06/22/delete-files-when-deleting-models-in-django/)

which deletes unreferenced files when instance is deleted.
one part of the code has this function:

```
""" Only delete the file if no other instances of that model are using it"""    
def delete_file_if_unused(model,instance,field,instance_file_field):
    dynamic_field = {}
    dynamic_field[field.name] = instance_file_field.name
    other_refs_exist = model.objects.filter(**dynamic_field).exclude(pk=instance.pk).exists()
    if not other_refs_exist:
        instance_file_field.delete(False)
```

What does the argument `False` mean in `.delete(False)`?

(I couldn't find a reference to it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implementation is specific to the FieldFile that code refers to, and it's for the `save` argument.

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.delete)

> FieldFile.delete(save=True)
>
> Deletes the file associated with this instance and clears all attributes on the field. Note: This method will close the file if it happens to be open when delete() is called.
>
> The optional save argument controls whether or not the model instance is saved after the file associated with this field has been deleted. Defaults to True.
>
> Note that when a model is deleted, related files are not deleted. If you need to cleanup orphaned files, you’ll need to handle it yourself (for instance, with a custom management command that can be run manually or scheduled to run periodically via e.g. cron).

Comment: thanks - so is FieldFile.delete(save=True),  equivalent to : FieldFile.delete(True) ?

Comment: Yes, arguments are positional by default so you can omit its name when following order (in this case just one). It’s a good idea though to include it for clarity, especially with a raw Boolean like this.